# Windows EC2 Networking: packets dropping if PPS is too high

Tags: windows, networking, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2019

I have a Windows 2019 Server running on AWS EC2 (m5.4xlarge) which is dropping packets under high pressure ("high" in this case is about 10K pps). The bandwidth is doing perfectly okay, the packets are small in size (about 100 bytes each, UDP).

The only thing I found so far is increasing the receive buffer on the Amazon Elastic Network Adapter, I maxed it out to 8192 - and it allowed the threshold to go a bit higher (to about 11.5K pps). However, it's still not enough, and the drops still occur.

I sadly don't have CPU metrics detailed enough, but I suspect it must be CPU not coping with clearing out the NIC buffers or something similar. Is there anything else I can tweak from the network side, some other buffers or whatnot; or should I be looking at increasing the CPU power at this point? Where else could/should I look?

Comment: What type of instance?

Comment: @GregAskew m5.4xlarge, updated the question.

Comment: Ok, that should have much higher throughput. Some of the c types are low throughput.

Comment: Yeah, as I'm saying, bandwidth is hardly utilized on the box.

Comment: I can't help directly, but I can say that AWS Support tends to be quite useful for the really complex questions that can depend on detailed knowledge of the infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you @Tim, if I don't find anything obvious soon I'll turn to them.

Comment: Did you enabled aws enhanced networking for windows?https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/enhanced-networking.html

Comment: @Turdie thank you for the pointer, I'll check when I have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:Example

For example, when there are three ENIs on a 72 vCPU instance with 2 NUMA nodes with hyper-threading enabled, the following commands spread the network load between the two CPUs without overlap and prevent the use of core 0 completely.

```
Set-NetAdapterRss -Name NIC1 -BaseProcessorGroup 0 -BaseProcessorNumber 2 -MaxProcessorNumber 16 
Set-NetAdapterRss -Name NIC2 -BaseProcessorGroup 1 -BaseProcessorNumber 0 -MaxProcessorNumber 14 
Set-NetAdapterRss -Name NIC3 -BaseProcessorGroup 1 -BaseProcessorNumber 16 -MaxProcessorNumber 30
```

Also check your MTU
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/enhanced-networking.html